# Is it possible to check if a type has been instantiated with a specific template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Not quite sure if my terminology is 100% correct, so here's the code:

```cpp
template<class... Ts>
struct Empty { };

int main() {
   using T = Empty<int, double>;
   // How to check if T "contains" double?

   return 0;
}
```

So this is specifically for types that accept multiple template types. Also this would ideally be at compile time. Bonus points if it doesn't need an object of the type.

The closest I was able to get (with [help](https://old.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/l4tup1/is_it_possible_to_check_if_a_type_has_been/)) was this:

```cpp
template <class check, class T, class... U>
constexpr bool contains_type(){
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, check>)
      return true;
   else if constexpr (sizeof...(U) > 0)
      return contains_type<check, U...>();
   else
      return false;
}


template <class check, template<class> class TypeToCheck, class... T>
constexpr bool does_obj_contain_type(TypeToCheck<T...>) {
   if constexpr (sizeof...(T) > 0)
      return contains_type<check, T...>();
   else
      return false;
}

constexpr bool does_contain_double = does_obj_contain_type<double>(T{});
```

That contains C++ syntax I've never before seen, but it works. Would be neat if it wouldn't require the `T{}` object. And maybe look a bit saner.

Comment: You can replace `T{}` with `std::declval<T>()`

Comment: Oh right, I read about it and thought someday I'll use it. The day has some, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want... but I suppose is something as

```
template <class check, template<class...> class TypeToCheck, class... T>
constexpr bool does_obj_contain_type(TypeToCheck<T...>) {
   return (std::is_same_v<check, T> || ...);
}

// ...

using T = Empty<int, double>;

auto x = does_obj_contain_type<double>(T{});
```

But it's a problem if you can't instantiate an object of type `T`. In the case, I suppose you can use class/struct specialization.

Something as

```
template <typename>
struct does_obj_contain_type;

template <template <typename...> class TTC, typename ... Ts>
struct does_obj_contain_type<TTC<Ts...>>
 {
   template <typename check>
   static constexpr bool func ()
    { return (std::is_same_v<check, Ts> || ...); }
 };

 // ...

 using T = Empty<int, double>;

 constexpr auto x = does_obj_contain_type<T>::func<double>();
```

Or maybe better as a template variable `value` (suggested by super: thanks!)

```
template <template <typename...> class TTC, typename ... Ts>
struct does_obj_contain_type<TTC<Ts...>>
 {
   template <typename Check>
   static constexpr auto value = (std::is_same_v<Check, Ts> || ...);
 };

// ...

using T = Empty<int, double>;

constexpr auto x = does_obj_contain_type<T>::value<double>;
```

Comment: @eerorika - If I'm not wrong, folding with `||` is `false`, in case of empy list.

Comment: That's so much simpler, thank you. Bummer that it doesn't seem to be possible without the parameter. But with `std::declval` it shouldn't be too ugly.

Comment: @Basti - added an alternative version, in case you don't want instantiate an object of type `T` (caution: code not tested).

Comment: I see. Not a problem in practice, I was mostly curious if it's possible. Thanks again.

Comment: @Basti - If you don't need an object of type `T`, something that check the type itself instead an object is preferable (IMHO). Unfortunately, require a little more typewriting.

Comment: @max66 I remember having problems using unary folds with empty argument lists, but this does seem to work.

Comment: You can replace `func` with `static constexpr bool value = ...`. But I guess that's more a matter of style.

Comment: @eeroica - yes, but for `||`, `&&` and `,` there are special rules for the empty case.

Comment: @super - that is a template variable... available only starting from C++14 but, if we're using folding, we're using C++17 so is available... I like it; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The question has already been answered but I'll just throw in an expansion if you'd like to unwrap layers of `Empty<>`s at some point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// non templated types
template<class check, class... Ts>
struct contains_type {
    static constexpr bool value = (std::is_same_v<check, Ts> || ...);
};

// templated types
template <class check, template<class...> class TypeToCheck, class... Ts>
struct contains_type<check, TypeToCheck<Ts...>> {
    static constexpr bool value = 
        (std::is_same_v<check, Ts> || ...) ||     // if "check" is templated
        (contains_type<check, Ts>::value || ...); // unwrap one layer
};

// Helper variable template
template<class... Ts>
inline constexpr bool contains_type_v = contains_type<Ts...>::value;

template<class... Ts>
struct Empty { };

int main() {
   using False = Empty<int, float, float, long double>;
   using True = Empty<int, double, int>;
   using DoubleNestFalse = Empty<Empty<int>, Empty<int, float>>;
   using DoubleNestTrue = Empty<Empty<int>, Empty<double, float>>;
   
   std::cout << std::boolalpha;

   std::cout << contains_type_v<double, False> << '\n';
   std::cout << contains_type_v<double, True> << '\n';
   
   std::cout << contains_type_v<double, float> << '\n';              // false
   std::cout << contains_type_v<double, int, double> << '\n';        // true
 
   std::cout << contains_type_v<double, DoubleNestFalse> << '\n';
   std::cout << contains_type_v<double, DoubleNestTrue> << '\n';

   std::cout << contains_type_v<Empty<int>, DoubleNestTrue> << '\n'; // true
}
```